# Converting Prototype AJAX Call with RJS to just jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, prototypejs

I am running a Rails 3.0 Application with Prototype and RJS. I want to convert over to just use jQuery.

My questions are

**1. Is it possible to just get rid of RJS completely when using jQuery?**

and

**2. If not, how do I convert the following:**

I have the following DIV element in my **index.html.erb**:

```
<div id="students"></div>
```

I have a **ajaxCalls.js.erb** containing the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<%=populate_students_path()%>',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'authenticity_token=' + AUTH_TOKEN,
    dataType: 'html', // Consider changing to HTML if this doesnt work
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript");
    }
  }).done(function (data) {

    // TODO Populate table with populate function
    var users_table = $('#students').dataTable({
      'aData': data
    });
  });
```

In which I get the following response:

```
try {
populate("{\"54\":{\"section\":\"-\",\"filter_table_row_contents\":\"<td>\\n  c5leharf\\n</td>\\n<td>\\n  Lehar\\n</td>\\n<td>\\n  Franz}")
}
```

I have a **populate.rjs** which contains:

```
page.call "populate", @students.to_json
```

Which *may* call the following, but I am unsure:

```
function populate(json_data) {
  users_table.populate(json_data);
  users_table.render();
}
```

So, the question here is**

### How do I make my response render correctly? How do I remove the populate function from the data retrieved from the AJAX call? How do I get just plain JSON?

**Edit: Kaeros's answer worked, with my controller looking like:**

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => @students_data } 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an ajax method like the one you are using (expecting json from the server):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<%=populate_students_path()%>',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'authenticity_token=' + AUTH_TOKEN,
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript");
    }
  }).done(function (data) {
    //Do something with the data received as json
  });
```

And in you controller method you just have to return json.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: @some_instance_variable }
end
```

Comment: ajax method is the same, just had to change my controller method to be appropriate for Rails 3.0. See my updated original post.